# Gmail keyboard shortcut for bulleted/numbered lists

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

When I'm composing a message, I want to start a bulleted or numbered list with a keyboard shortcut instead of using the mouse.  How can I do this?

If there is no way to do these things, what's the preferred way of requesting such shortcuts from Google?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> for a numbered list
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> for a bulleted list

It's the same as in Google Docs.

Comment: Works with the new Gmail.  Thanks!

Comment: The answer used to be correct. Alas in the past few months, these keyboard shortcuts no longer work for me. Any idea why?

Comment: @Farrel: They work for me.

Comment: Cmd + Shift + 8 for bulleted list in Gmail on Mac

Answer (score 1):

There is a keyboard shortcut for this in Google Docs -- Ctrl+Shift+7 for a numbered list, or Ctrl+Shift+8 for a bulleted list -- but that shortcut doesn't (yet?) work in GMail, unfortunately.